# "No suitable driver found" em conexão de banco de dados em Java

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom, uso o eclipse e estou tentando conectar um banco de dados MySQL com o meu projeto, meu código, comparado a outros tutorias que achei, está perfeito, e é esse:

```
package pack;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Banco {

public Statement stm;
public ResultSet rs;
public Connection conn;
public String Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

public void Conecta(){
    System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", Driver);
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:meu_caminho", "meu_login", "minha_senha");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro!" + "\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void Desconecta(){
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao fechar!");
    }
}

}
```

o problema é que dá o erro de "No suitable driver found for meu_caminho"

a solução que todos dizem é que eu tenho que colocar o driver do jdbc no meu projeto, tentei baixar no próprio site do Mysql o conector do java, porém é um arquivo msi, e o que todos os tutoriais dizem são para colocar o .jar, mas eu não encontro de jeito nenhum esse jar, o único que eu encontrei foi num link do 4shared, uma versão 5.1.13 em .jar, mas mesmo depois que eu adiciono a biblioteca, o mesmo erro continua dando...

alguem sabe aonde eu consigo esse .jar?

Obs: sobre esse .jar que eu achei, eu coloquei ele no projeto, cliquei no botão direito, fui em propriedades, java build path, adicionei o .jar, foi criado a pasta de Referenced libraries, e quando eu abro, está lá o "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" e ainda sim, ele NÃO conecta...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você precisa carregar a classe com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Exemplo:

```
public void Conecta(){
    //System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", Driver);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //adicione essa linha
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:meu_caminho", "meu_login", "minha_senha");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro!" + "\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Class.forName() faz com que a classe passada como argumento seja carregada dinamicamente a classe que chama ela. E o seu erro acusa justamente a falta do Driver apropriado.

Não sei exatamente o que o `System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", Driver);` faz, mas parece que foi uma tentativa falha de adicionar a classe do Driver, comente essa linha e adicione a linha que eu indiquei acima.

Comment: Math, cheguei nessa resposta a partir de outra pergunta. Queria deixar só um comentário, a partir do Java SE 6 (JDBC 4.0) chamadas explícitas para `Class.forName` não são mais necessárias (vide documentação do [DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)). Tem uma galerinha forte usando Java 5 ou drivers legados por aí :).

Comment: Pois é, eu havia lido isso no link da pergunta duplicada dessa aq, dai eu ia testar para ver se procede, mas ainda nao tive tempo. Fato curioso tantas pessoas tendo esse tipo de problema.