# Aplicativo funciona no eclipse e deixa de funcionar após gerar o executável JAR

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Estou trabalhando em dois aplicativos aqui na empresa que estão me dando uma certa dor de cabeça por um motivo que a solução deve ser simples mais não estou conseguindo localizar o erro, os dois aplicativos funcionam normalmente dentro do eclipse, mais quando gero o .JAR e executo os programas fora do eclipse ele gera um erro referente ao banco de dados.

O mais engraçado é que um dos programas dá o mesmo erro porém para o drive do banco de dados Oracle 11g o outro funciona o Oracle 11g e dá problema no drive do uncanaccess.

O que pode ser?

---

Problema foi resolvido através do comentário do Denis, foi necessário adicionar a declaração abaixo no código;

```
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20722/no-suitable-driver-found-em-conex%C3%A3o-de-banco-de-dados-em-java, verifica esse caso, também certifique-se que o driver está dentro do jar

Comment: Amigo solucionou os dois problemas, obrigado, atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Vou postar como resposta, assim dá para saber que a pergunta foi respondida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder corrigir esse problema é necessário registrar o driver a ser utilizado, para isso é necessário utilizar `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver")`, dessa forma o driver é carregado e você consegue abrir a conexão sem problemas